# Logging in user into Parse returns IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm currently stuck on an error that I can't solve. I tried everything, and can't seem to find similar questions that answer my question.

I am currently working on an Android application, and using Parse SDK as a back-end service. Suddenly, whenever I try to log the user into the server, it returns this error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value == null

Trying to figure the problem, I tried digging into the error message. I tried to print more information toward the process. Here is a snippet on how I execute the login process into Parse

```
UserModel.logInInBackground(email, pwd, new LogInCallback() {
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (user != null) {
                // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                Log.d("ParseLogin", "Login is successful! Logged in as "+user.getEmail());
                Log.d("ParseLogin", "Token "+user.getSessionToken());

                //on success call this one
                onLoginSuccess();
            } else {
                // Signup failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened.
                Log.d("ParseLogin", "Login failed!");
                Log.d("ParseLogin", String.valueOf(e.getCode()));
                Log.d("ParseLogin", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.d("ParseLogin", e.getMessage());

                //on failed attempt call this one
                onLoginFailed(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

The printout error was not so helpful after all

> D/ParseLogin: Login failed! 
>   D/ParseLogin: -1 
>   D/ParseLogin: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value == null 
>   D/ParseLogin: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value == null

I trace back into the input values. They seem to be fine, and also match with the database saved on Parse. Now, I can't do any login at all. **Does anyone have any insights on this problem?**

Comment: parse.com has ended there service

Comment: I am using the open source version that Parse has provided from Github

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was by removing OKhttp from my dependency. I think Parse doesn't play very well with it.